# Array of arrays being mutated with slice, spread, and map

Tags: javascript, arrays

This question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42780264/array-is-being-mutated-when-using-slice) and more importantly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597588/how-do-you-clone-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript). I tried all the answers and none solved my issue. It's very basic.

I have the following array. My various attempts at copying do not persist after splicing, or performing any destructive action. Even the copies are mutated. How can I copy this so the original version persists?

```
var arrs = [ [ 3 ], [ 7, 4 ], [ 2, 4, 6 ], [ 8, 5, 9, 3 ] ]

var arrsCopy1 = arrs.slice()

var arrsCopy2 = arrs.map(arr => {
  return arr
})

var arrsCopy3 = [...arrs]


//test one of the copies
arrsCopy3.forEach(arr => {
  return arr.splice(0, arr.length)
})
arrs, arrsCopy1, arrsCopy2, arrsCopy3 => [[],[],[],[]]
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/chri_del/pen/KEVpBL?editors=0010) is a fiddle that demos my problem (using `reverse()` instead of `splice`)

Comment: Calling out myself for duplication https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41786946/splice-doesnt-copy-array-of-objects?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `JSON` methods:

```
var arrCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it recursively

```
const copyArr = (element) => {
    //If the element is a primitive
    if (element !== Object(element)) {
        return element;
    //The element is an array
    } else {
        return element.map(subelement => copyArr(subelement));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41786946/splice-doesnt-copy-array-of-objects?noredirect=1&lq=1) and it seems to solve the issue.

I was thrown off my the `JSON.parse`.

`var clonedArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(originalArray));`

Comment: Yes, serialize/deserialize should recreate all objects.